# Is there a topology for nondecreasing continuous functions?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, order-theory, monotone-functions

Let $I=[0,1]$ be the unit interval, with $\tau_0$ the usual topology.

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4779777/1210477), I've been wondering whether it is possible to topologize $I$ so that the continuous functions are precisely the usual continuous functions that are also nondecreasing.  That is,

> Is there another topology $\tau$ on $I$ such that $f\colon I\to I$ is $\tau$-continuous if and only if it is $\tau_0$-continuous and nondecreasing?

(Here by $\tau$-continuous we mean continuous when both domain and codomain are equipped with $\tau$.)

There are some related topologies in this vein. If we only want to get nondecreasing functions (i.e., $f$ is continuous iff $f$ is nondecreasing), we have the [Alexandrov topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4657105/1210477) given by: $$\tau_a=\{U\in \mathcal P(I)\mid x\in U\wedge y\geq x\implies y\in U\}$$

Similarly, if we let $\tau_-=\{(a,1]\mid 0\leq a<1 \}\cup\{\emptyset\}$, it is routine to verify $f$ is $\tau_-$-continuous if and only if $f$ is nondecreasing and $\tau_0$-continuous from the left. We could similarly get right continuity by defining $\tau_+=\{[0,a)\mid 0<a\leq 1\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$.

However, these kinds of simple constructions don't seem to have an obvious way to modify them to get all nondecreasing continuous functions - trying to combine the open sets in $\tau_+$ and $\tau_-$ gives us back $\tau_0$, so we lose monotonicity.

I'd be very interested in either an example of such a topology $\tau$ or a proof that one cannot exist.

More generally, one can replace $I$ with any totally ordered set $T$ with its order topology, and ask the same question.  The topologies $\tau_a$, $\tau_+$, and $\tau_-$ defined above all generalize easily, and as a result, it is easy to see that if $T$ is any well-ordered set, or more generally, any total ordered set in which every element has an immediate successor, the answer is yes, since we can just take $\tau_-$, as every function is already continuous from the right.  But it would be interesting to know if there are other examples.

Comment: In your question, does both domain and codomain have the same topology $\tau$? There's four types of continuity to consider here, $\tau$-$\tau$-continuous, $\tau$-$\tau_0$-continuous, $\tau_0$-$\tau$-continuous and $\tau_0$-$\tau_0$-continuous.

Comment: @Jakobian yes, at least that's what I had in mind.  I hadn't really considered the case of two different topologies, though, I think that could still be potentially interesting.

Comment: Also keep in mind that even if we did allow differing topologies on domain and codomain, at minimum we cannot use $\tau_0$ on the domain, since we could always precompose with the map $x\to 1-x$ and turn a nondecreasing function into a nonincreasing one. [actually I guess this applies to codomain and postcomposition as well].

Comment: Some observations of mine: If such topology $\tau$ exists, then $(I, \tau)$ is connected and $\tau_0\subseteq \tau$.